# android: system-wide audio loudness normalization

Tags: android, audio, daemon

i'd like to write an android app that equalizes loudness (turns down volume during loud sounds) of all media audio in real time. something like a dynamic compressor/normalizer.

i'd like pointers to examples of how to get started.  ie, how to write an app that constantly runs in the background and monitors/modifies all media audio, without root if possible.  what frameworks/libraries are appropriate?

i haven't done mobile app development before, but am an experienced programmer and have a basic (probably naive) idea of how to normalize loudness -- so i'm not looking for discussion of the algorithm.

i couldn't find any existing apps out there, although that's hard to believe.  if you know of one, please send a link so i can study it.